# how to validate rawTx in bitcoinCash

Tags: bitcoin-cash, raw-transaction

I am implementing Bitcoincash by **bitcoincashjs** module using Nodejs.

Referring site from below,
https://github.com/bitcoincashjs/bitcoincashjs/blob/master/docs/examples.md#create-a-transaction

In that all API's works fine but when I am trying to do transactions it returns me an rawtx string as,

> 01000000016889302ea03e.............................ffffffff01983a0000000000001976a914ad618cf4333b3b248f9744e8e81db2964d0ae39788ac00000000

But I want,

1) to decode this rawtx to get what actually message it returns ?

2) & how to determine the transaction is successfull or fails ?